# Simple jQuery Simple Solution?

Tags: jquery

```
<button type="button" id="overlay-close">Close</button>           
</nav>
    </div>  
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".overlay").hide();
$('#overlay-menu').click(function(){
$('.overlay').fadeIn(300);

});

$("overlay-close").click(function(){
$('.overlay').fadeOut("slow");

});
});


 </script>
```

Any ideas on getting this to work?

Fade in is fine, Fade Out onClick Function not fading Out.

Go here to see it click on hamburger menu toggle

http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/cyfa

Comment: `$("overlay-close")` should be `$("#overlay-close")`

Answer (score 0):

overlay-close is not an element in html. your code should be like this

```
$("#overlay-close").click(function(){
$('.overlay').fadeOut("slow");

});
```

Comment: I've uniformed all quotes to be double-quotes also, but still the click function is having no effect.

Comment: maybe something else in your javascript code is breaking. can you add a quick jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre solution, when I pasted

into JS Fiddle, there were some hidden unicode chars showing up as red circles, that were basically breaking the code and stopping from working with the DOM effectively.

I think I copied that HTML from another site and the hidden chars came along with it.

Obscure but that's what it is.

Works fine now!

Thanks for helping.